# SQL SELECT to find cyclic references in father-ID-organized tree?

Tags: sql, oracle, cyclic-reference

"Fun" with cyclic references:

Suppose I have a table ELEMENTS which contain a hierarchy of elements, modeled by a father ID.

The father ID field is null for the root.

All other records have a non-null father id with the (autosequenced) primary key (`ID`) of the father element.

For example, using

```
SELECT *
FROM Elements
WHERE FATHER_ID not in (SELECT ID FROM Elements)
```

I can find all elements that have invalid father references (`FATHER_ID` is not a foreign key, let's assume that in this example).

**But how can I find elements that do have a valid father reference BUT whose chain of father references does not end in the root?** I think this can only happen for cyclic references, for example A is the father of B, but B is the father of A, too. Such a "subtree" is not linked to the root and thus is not part of the main tree. **I want to find such subtrees.**

Of course, I am looking for a query that delivers those elements that lead to a cyclic reference no matter how long the chain of references may be.

**Is that possible in SQL, or do I need an iterative solution?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  n.*, CONNECT_BY_ROOT(id), level
FROM    elements n
START WITH
        id IN
        (
        SELECT  MIN(id)
        FROM    (
                SELECT  id, CONNECT_BY_ROOT(id) AS root
                FROM    elements
                START WITH
                        id IN
                        (
                        SELECT  id
                        FROM    elements n
                        WHERE   CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE = 1
                        CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
                                father_id = PRIOR id
                        )
                CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
                        id = PRIOR father_id
                )
        GROUP BY
                root
        )
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
        id = PRIOR father_id
```

You may want to read this article:

- [**Finding loops in a tree**](http://explainextended.com/2009/05/18/finding-loops-in-a-tree/)

Comment: +1 for use of CONNECT BY. There's all sorts of great things it can do with hierarchical data. Note that it is Oracle-only. In 11gR2 they added the recursive subquery factoring clause (http://technology.amis.nl/blog/6104/oracle-rdbms-11gr2-goodbye-connect-by-or-the-end-of-hierarchical-querying-as-we-know-it)

Comment: Oha. That looks like something to churn on, and being worth it. Thanks.