# Oracle SQL Find Circular Prerequisites

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, prerequisites

I have two tables as defined below:

```
    Course(Worker_id, Course_id)
          Primary key is (Worker_id, Course_id)

    Prerequisite(Course_id, Prerequisite_id)
          Primary key is (Course_id, Prerequisite_id)
```

I would like to be able to find all circular prerequisites. For example, if CourseA was a prerequisite for CourseB and CourseB was a prerequisite for CourseA (simplified example). My result should be the name of the courses that have unsatisfiable prerequisites, in this case both CourseA and CourseB.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0

Comment: For cases that can have more than 2 courses in the cycle, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5803666/4479309) for a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( Course_id, ' -> ' ) AS path
FROM   prerequisites
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE = 1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR Course_id = Prerequisite_id;
```

Comment: that doesn't work if the cycle has more than two items in it (eg. course A requires course B which requires course C which requires course A). Or rather, it'll give you the start and end of the cycle, but not any values in between - ie. course B wouldn't be reported as being in a cycle.

Comment: seems to work fine for me? includes every course that is part of the cycle

Comment: @Boneist - sys_connect_by_path will list all nodes along the path.